# I was really young. “I don’t even remember what is about” vs “I don’t remember what it was about”

Tags: tense, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

I have a question about the tenses in a sentence. Hope you can help me.

Situation:
I was talking to a friend and I goes
“looks like everyone is watching “Love Actually” for xmas. I watched it once when I was really young. I don’t even remember what is about”

So, I was wondering what tenses should use for “remember” and “be” in the last sentence.

Don’t or didn’t?
(Though to my sense, I’m quite sure I should use present tense here, as I don’t remenber now and in general situation.)

Is or was?
(Not sure about this one. Both sound correct to me. If it was a thing in the past, I guess I should use past tense. However, the moive is still exsisting, so I’m not sure about it)

Side questions from about content:
1. Should I use “I was talking to a friend and I GOES” or “I was talking to a friend and I WENT”?
2. Should I use “Both sound” or “Both sounds”?

Thank you and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

From context it seems clear that you should say

> I **don't** even remember what it **is** about.

This means that at the moment you do not recall what the movie is about because it has been a long time since you have seen it.  On the other hand if you were to say

> I **didn't** even remember what it **was** about.

Then you are saying that at some point in the past someone asked about about it and at that time you were unable to recall what it was about.  This latter phrase makes it unclear whether you know what it's about now or not.

Comment: Thank you. Is “I don’t remember what it was about” grammatically incorrect?

Comment: It would be fine to say "I don't remember what it was about."  In that case you are referring to the instance when you first watched it a little more specifically.  You have forgotten the details of that experience.  If you say "I don't remember what it is about," then you are generally saying you currently don't know what the movie is about.

Comment: I can see their differences from your explanation. Their differences are subtle. I've a rather vague question below, as I don't know how I should put this and what situation I should give. Should I use present tense for all or most of the general issues like expressing my ideas, my thoughts toward a thing like here the movie, unless I want to stress exactly when was is happen. So, it is like it's never too wrong to use present tense.